# Best way to see if a view file (.ctp) exists in Cake PHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, view

I am using CakePHP 3, and would like to change the behaviour of the handy PagesController which comes with the installation.

The current solution they use when trying to find and render a view file (.ctp) is using a try{} block, which is working well. 
Actual code:

```
try {
        $this->render(implode('/', $path));
} catch (MissingTemplateException $e) {
```

But in my case the most common situation will be that the .ctp file *does not* exist. (If it does not exist, it will go on with a default view and try fetch content from database, but it is not my problem here.)

In my modified version the most normal case will be that the MissingTemplaceException is thrown, which seem a bit overkill. 
Why can I not simply check if the file exists?

Am I thinking right here? And if I am, how do I check for the file's existence?

---

After some fiddling around, I found the APP constant. This works:

```
$path = func_get_args();
$file = APP.'Template'.DS.'Pages'.DS.implode('/', $path).'.ctp';
if (file_exists($file))
{
  // Render the file.
}
else
{
  // Render some default file.
}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply execute your default code in the catch block instead of throwing an exception?

Comment: @arilia - That's what I currently do, it works. I just think it would be faster to check if the file exists instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why can I not simply check if the file exists?

I don't know why *you* can't. Just use [file_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)?

```
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "The file $filename exists";
} else {
    echo "The file $filename does not exist";
}
```

Comment: Sorry @burzum, I was not very clear in my question. What I would like to know is how do I get the same file-name as $this->render(implode('/', $path)); must produce and then render. An example: $path='that-page', which in the end will make $this->render() look for  the file Template/Pages/that-page.ctp.

Comment: See my edited answer, I believe the major problem here was that I was sleeping. :P ;)